# Regex - Match all characters except those in certain words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture all characters a-z, A-Z (non-numeric) except for those that are in a certain word (Javascript):

ie:

```
For words: sin, cos, ln

input:

sins12  <== should capture 4th character s
cosb12  <== should capture 4th character b
alnb11  <== should capture 1st character a and 4th character b
```

I have tried using the following:
`^(?!sin$|cos$).*`

However, this captures the entire line which is not what I am looking for.

What is the easiest way to do this? Negative lookahead?

Comment: What should be result for `acosin45` ?

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest just doing a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = ["sins12", "cosb12", "alnb11"];
input.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var output = item.replace(/(?:sin|cos|ln)|[^a-z]/ig, "");
    console.log(item + " => " + output);
});
```

The regex does a global case insensitive replacement removal of the following:

```
(?:sin|cos|ln)    the keywords "sin", "cos", or "ln"
|                 OR
[^a-z]            anything else which is not a letter
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about `?:` part?

Comment: @Tân The `?:` just tells the regex engine to make the alternation `(?:sin|cos|ln)` a _non capturing_ group.  Normally, putting something into parentheses tells the regex engine to capture it.  We don't want that here.